Nginx regex k8s issues
I am attempting to deploy the grafana image renderer using 3 k8s manifests. 1 is a deploy, 2 is a service, and 3 is an ingress. The Nginx ingress regex rules say they are PCRE and I am attempting that.
I need the regex to capture this path (input text): grafana.host/render/d/4DFTt9Wnk/nginx-performance?orgId=1
Below are the k8s files I used:
deploy:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: grafana-image-renderer
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: grafana-image-renderer
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: grafana-image-renderer
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: grafana-image-renderer
          image: grafana/grafana-image-renderer:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
              name: http
          env:
            - name: ENABLE_METRICS
              value: "true"
            - name: ENABLE_METRICS_ENDPOINT
              value: "true"
            - name: TZ
              value: "UTC"
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 8081
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 8081
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 20
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 1Gi
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
              memory: 2Gi

svc
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grafana-renderer-svc
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  selector:
    app: grafana-image-renderer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
  type: ClusterIP

ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: grafana-render-ingress
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    spec.ingressClassName: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: grafana.host # domain
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        path: '/render/d/4DFTt9Wnk/^([!-~]+)?'
        backend:
          service:
            name: grafana-image-svc
            port:
              number: 8081


I have no idea why the regex for nginx isn't capturing this group. I've used https://regex101.com/ to get the best regex for this group and it still doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Firstly, the ^ character refers to the start of a line, so I would think that is the first problem. You say you used regex101.com yet what I see in your code inserted into that website shows up issues. This was my interpretation of what you had on that website: https://regex101.com/r/3REiPy/1
